# Windows 10 Slow USB 3.0 Disk Transfer (~30.0 MB/s)

Tags: windows, usb-3

**-Question-**
What is causing Windows 10 to write data to a USB 3.0 drive at only ~30.0 MB/s?

**-Details-**
When copying files from an internal desktop SATA3 disk to an external USB 3.0 drive, the write speed is on average about 30.0 MB/s.

**-Hypothesis-**
It may be possible both the OS and the USB drive have fallen back to USB 2.0 (if so, would there be a way to check if a transfer is actually occurring over USB 3.0. *Update: See -Research- below for a method found in another question*.)?

Even though Windows 10 is reporting the presence of a USB 3.0 controller, perhaps a problem in the driver is causing a fallback to USB 2.0.

**-Research-**
A similar issue in Windows 8:

[Why can I transfer only 35 MB/s to my USB 3.0 external hard disk?](https://superuser.com/questions/634684/why-can-i-transfer-only-35-mb-s-to-my-usb-3-0-external-hard-disk)

Determine if a device connected via USB 2.0 or USB 3.0:

[Verifying USB connection speed (USB 3 or USB 2?)](https://superuser.com/questions/478184/verifying-usb-connection-speed-usb-3-or-usb-2?rq=1)

**-Product Info-**
Seagate 1 TB SATA3 Desktop Drive:

http://www.seagate.com/internal-hard-drives/desktop-hard-drives/desktop-hdd/#specs

Seagate 1 TB USB3  Backup Drive:

http://www.seagate.com/products/laptop-mobile-storage/laptop-external-drives/backup-plus-slim/

**-System Details-**
CPU: Intel Core i7 - Windows 10

RAM: 32 GB

Read Disk: Seagate 1 TB - 7200 RPM - Internal - 3.5 inch - SATA3 - ST1000DM003

Write Disk: Seagate 1 TB - 5400 RPM - External - 2.5 inch - USB 3.0 - STDR1000100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**-Simple Answer-**

Reboot computer.

**-Explanation-**

After rebooting system, transfer speed increased to around 100 MB/s, which is optimal for a 2.5 inch external USB 3.0 5400 RPM drive.

It appears Windows 10 loaded a driver for the drive during boot.

**-Cause-**

Unknown.